# Angular 7 Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7, angular-template

I'm getting error while retrieving data from the database.

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

I tried all the remaining responses but I'm not getting the exact solution.

my **service.ts**:

```
  users: User[];
  getAllUsers(){
    return this.http.get(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/users');
  }
```

my **component.ts**:

```
  refreshUserList(){
    this.userService.getAllUsers().subscribe((res) => {
      this.userService.users = res as User[];
    })
  };
```

my **component.html**:

```
<tr *ngFor="let use of userService.users">
  <td>{{ use.fullName }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you please console.log the response?

Comment: so you've done something weird. your response isn't typeof User[]. Try add response type in getAllUsers() method (User[]). and in http.get add this.http.get<User[]>(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/users');

Comment: {status: true, docs: Array(5)}  this is my console.log of response @dileepkumarjami

Comment: try  `*ngFor="let use of userService.users?.docs"` as you reference the wrong object in the template according to the console.log.

Comment: Thanks @ForestG it's working..

Comment: Displaying data from service inside template is not a good idea, better use component method or field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, use the below as you can see that the response is not an array but one of its fields is an array. So, you have to iterate on the array field.

```
*ngFor="let use of userService.users?.docs"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should store your users in a local array of `User` in the component, and user the `*ngFor` on the `users.docs`

**component.ts**:

```
users: User[];

refreshUserList(){
    this.userService.getAllUsers().subscribe(res => {
      res !== null : this.docs = res.docs;
    })
};
```

**component.html**:

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users?.docs">
  <td>{{ user.fullName }}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

In other way, you can check the data is ready to serve in html file by the following way.

```
<div *ngIf="userService.users?.length > 0">
   <tr *ngFor="let use of userService.users">
       <td>{{ use.fullName }}</td>
    </tr>
</div>
```